# Access and change data in a nested dict / list dataset Python 2.7+

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

I need some guidance with accessing and changing some values in a dataset. I'm using the Strava API, so its biking data. I have a list made of dictionaries that contain a string as the key, and a list as the value:

```
[{'ride_name_one':[1.3,7.5,8.2,4.8]},{'ride_name_2:'[4.7,6.8,8.9,4.3]}]
```

I have to convert each one of those values from m/s to km/h, and save it back to that list. How do I dig down to those lists to update them? I am guessing it is something like:

`streamsTest[0]['ride_name_one']`

except not sure how to make 'ride_name_one' dynamic?

OR

Is there a better spot to do this conversion?

Here's my code so far:

```
athleteID = [xxxxxxxx]
activityIDs = [xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx]

def getSpeeds(cIDs,aIDs):

    print cIDs
    print aIDs

    streamsTest = []

    for i in aIDs:
        aID = i
        types = ['velocity_smooth']
        streams = client.get_activity_streams(aID, types=types, resolution='low')
        activity = client.get_activity(aID)

        if 'velocity_smooth' in streams.keys():
            actName = activity.name 
            raw = streams['velocity_smooth'].data
            streamsTest.append({actName:raw})   
        else: 
            print "velocity_smooth is not available"

    print streamsTest
    #[{'key':[1,2,3,4]},{'key:'[1,2,3,4]}]
    ### do m/s to km/h conversion on nested list data


getSpeeds(athleteID,activityIDs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do it, tho if there is a nicer way, feel free to comment.

```
athleteID = [xxxxxxx]
activityIDs = [xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx]

def getSpeeds(cIDs,aIDs):

    streamsDicts = []
    streamsFinal = []

    for i in aIDs:
        aID = i
        types = ['velocity_smooth']
        streams = client.get_activity_streams(aID, types=types, resolution='low')
        activity = client.get_activity(aID) 
        if 'velocity_smooth' in streams.keys():
            actName = activity.name 
            raw = streams['velocity_smooth'].data
            streamsDicts.append({actName:raw[1:]})  
        else: 
            print "velocity_smooth is not available"

    for i in streamsDicts:
        for key, value in i.iteritems():
            value = [round((x * 3600) / 1000,2) for x in value]
            streamsFinal.append({key:value})

    print streamsFinal

getSpeeds(athleteID,activityIDs)
```